# limit on infinity

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to solve this question but I am  getting a negative infinity which is wrong.
$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\ln(e^{2x}-1)-\frac{x^2-3}{x}\right)$$ 
$$=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\ln(e^{2x}-1)-\frac{x(x^{ }-\frac{3}{x})}{x}\right)$$
$$=\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\ln(e^{2x}-1)-x\right)$$
$$=\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\left((e^{2x}-1)\frac{\ln(e^{2x}-1)}{e^{2x}-1}-x\right)$$
$$\lim \:_{x\to \:\infty \:}\:(-x)$$
$$=-\infty $$

Comment: How did you get from Step 2 to Step 3? Also, you have too many brackets for each step to make sense

Comment: And how do you get from step 4 to step 5? I don't think your cancellations make sense.

Comment: sir actually 3/x will go zero as i am neglecting and also the remaining x(x)/x will cancel with giving only result x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split up the $e^{2x}$ and you get

$$\ln(e^{2x}-1) - x+\frac 3x \stackrel{e^{2x}-1=e^{2x}(1-e^{-2x})}{=} \ln(e^{2x}) + \ln(1-e^{-2x}) - x+\frac 3x$$ $$=2x-x+\frac 3x + \ln(1-e^{-2x})=x+\frac 3x + \ln(1-e^{-2x})\stackrel{x \to +\infty}{\rightarrow}+\infty$$

Comment: actually answer log2 but when i put into desmos this function it actually does not exits

Comment: this question even my sir ask me to put on his email still i am waiting for his reply

Comment: @FeemoFellow : Maybe the graph can convince you that the limit is $+\infty$:
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28%5Cln%28e%5E%7B2x%7D-1%29-%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-3%7D%7Bx%7D%29%2C+x%3D0..20